# Encripting a message with RSA and another key

Tags: java, encryption

I'm trying to encrypt and decrypt a message in Java I get the same error all the time:

> java.security.InvalidKeyException: Key is too long for unwrapping

I'm trying to simulate sending encripted messages from a Server to a Client.

1st: The client generate a private and public key.

2nd The client sends the public key to the server.

3rd: The server generates the symmetric AES key.

4t: The server encrypts the text that he wants to send to the client with his AES key.

5e: The server encrypts the AES key with the public key received from the client.

6e: The server sends the encrypted text and the encrypted AES key to the client.

7e: The client decrypt the AES key with his private key.

8e: The client decrypts the text received from the server with the decrypted AES key.

```
public class Test {

    private static SecretKey secretKey;
    private static KeyPair keyPair;
    private static final String STRINGTOENCRYPT = "This is a test";
    private static String stringEncripted;
    private static String keyEncripted;
    public static final byte[] IV_PARAM = {0x00, 0x01, 0x02, 0x03,
            0x04, 0x05, 0x06, 0x07,
            0x08, 0x09, 0x0A, 0x0B,
            0x0C, 0x0D, 0x0E, 0x0F};


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        generateKeys();
    }

    private static void generateKeys() {

        secretKey = generateSecretKey(128);
        keyPair = generateKeyPair(512);
        stringEncripted = encriptString(STRINGTOENCRYPT);
        keyEncripted = encriptKey(keyPair.getPublic());

        decryptString();

    }

    private static void decryptString() {
        Cipher cipher = null;
        Key keyDecrypted = null;
        try {
            cipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA/ECB/PKCS1Padding");
            cipher.init(Cipher.UNWRAP_MODE, keyPair.getPrivate());
            keyDecrypted = cipher.unwrap(keyEncripted.getBytes(), "AES", Cipher.SECRET_KEY);

            cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
            IvParameterSpec iv = new IvParameterSpec(IV_PARAM);
            cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, keyDecrypted, iv);
            byte[] stringDecryptedBytes = cipher.doFinal(stringEncripted.getBytes());
            String stringDecrypted = new String(stringDecryptedBytes);

            System.out.println(stringDecrypted);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }


    private static KeyPair generateKeyPair(int lenght) {
        KeyPair keyPublicAndPrivate = null;

        try {
            KeyPairGenerator keyGen = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("RSA");
            keyGen.initialize(lenght);
            keyPublicAndPrivate = keyGen.genKeyPair();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        return keyPublicAndPrivate;

    }

    private static SecretKey generateSecretKey(int lenght) {


        SecretKey sKey = null;
        if ((lenght == 128) || (lenght == 192) || (lenght == 256)) {
            try {
                KeyGenerator kgen = KeyGenerator.getInstance("AES");
                kgen.init(lenght);
                sKey = kgen.generateKey();
            } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return sKey;

    }

    private static String encriptString(String stringtoencrypt) {

        byte[] stringtoencryptBytes = stringtoencrypt.getBytes();
        Cipher cipher = null;

        String stringEncrypted = null;
        try {
            cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
            IvParameterSpec iv = new IvParameterSpec(IV_PARAM);
            cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, secretKey, iv);

            byte[] stringEncryptedBytes = cipher.doFinal(stringtoencryptBytes);
            stringEncrypted = new String(cipher.doFinal(stringtoencryptBytes), "UTF-8");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


        return stringEncrypted;
    }


    private static String encriptKey(PublicKey aPublic) {
        String keyEncryptedString = null;
        try {
            Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA/ECB/PKCS1Padding");
            cipher.init(Cipher.WRAP_MODE, aPublic);
            byte[] keyEncriptedBytes = cipher.wrap(secretKey);
            keyEncryptedString = new String(keyEncriptedBytes, "UTF-8");

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return keyEncryptedString;
    }

}
```

Any idea why it's happening?

Comment: try to decrypt the aes key with the private key..

Comment: Already changed that, but I'm getting the same error

Comment: This is *probably* not what's causing the error, but I hope you know that 512 bit RSA is pretty easily breakable nowadays. You should use [at least 2048 bit RSA keys](https://www.keylength.com/), and preferably longer.

Comment: Full stack trace please and the location in the code where it appears. Not in the comments but in the question.

Comment: @IlmariKaronen I'll post an answer, it is the string encoding. 512 bit RSA is 64 bytes and PKCS#1 has a constant overhead of only 11 bytes. OAEP starts at 42 byte s overhead, so that would be a bit tight.

Comment: Modern (computer) crypto (both AES and RSA, and many other things like SHA2) produces bytes containing apparently random bits, not valid character codes. Trying to 'decode' such bytes into a Java `String` and later recover them generally doesn't work. Preferably use bytes or a lossless encoding like hex or base64; if you must use raw characters try 'charset' `ISO-8859-1`, which identity-maps all octet values (0-255) to Unicode block 0, but on most JVM instances is not the default

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you cannot just assume that RSA or AES encryption results in bytes that represent a string. When you generate the strings using `new String` it will silently remove all bytes that do not represent characters. You can use `CharsetDecoder` if you want to have more control and throw an exception (which should have been the default).

The problem is that when you reconvert to bytes that some bytes may be missing. That means that the number may be significantly smaller, which will throw an exception one way or another as the input of unwrap is now too small.

Here are some changes that show how to get it working. I just commented out your code so you can compare.

```
import java.security.Key;
import java.security.KeyPair;
import java.security.KeyPairGenerator;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;
import java.security.PublicKey;

import javax.crypto.Cipher;
import javax.crypto.KeyGenerator;
import javax.crypto.SecretKey;
import javax.crypto.spec.IvParameterSpec;

public class Test {

    private static SecretKey secretKey;
    private static KeyPair keyPair;
    private static final String STRINGTOENCRYPT = "This is a test";
    private static String stringEncripted;
    private static byte[] ct;
    private static String keyEncripted;
    private static byte[] wrapped;
    public static final byte[] IV_PARAM = {0x00, 0x01, 0x02, 0x03,
            0x04, 0x05, 0x06, 0x07,
            0x08, 0x09, 0x0A, 0x0B,
            0x0C, 0x0D, 0x0E, 0x0F};


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        generateKeys();
    }

    private static void generateKeys() {

        secretKey = generateSecretKey(128);
        keyPair = generateKeyPair(512);
        stringEncripted = encriptString(STRINGTOENCRYPT);
        keyEncripted = encriptKey(keyPair.getPublic());

        decryptString();

    }

    private static void decryptString() {
        Cipher cipher = null;
        Key keyDecrypted = null;
        try {
            cipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA/ECB/PKCS1Padding");
            cipher.init(Cipher.UNWRAP_MODE, keyPair.getPrivate());
            // keyDecrypted = cipher.unwrap(keyEncripted.getBytes(), "AES", Cipher.SECRET_KEY);
            keyDecrypted = cipher.unwrap(wrapped, "AES", Cipher.SECRET_KEY);

            cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
            IvParameterSpec iv = new IvParameterSpec(IV_PARAM);
            cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, keyDecrypted, iv);
            byte[] stringDecryptedBytes = cipher.doFinal(ct);
            String stringDecrypted = new String(stringDecryptedBytes);

            System.out.println(stringDecrypted);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }


    private static KeyPair generateKeyPair(int lenght) {
        KeyPair keyPublicAndPrivate = null;

        try {
            KeyPairGenerator keyGen = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("RSA");
            keyGen.initialize(lenght);
            keyPublicAndPrivate = keyGen.genKeyPair();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        return keyPublicAndPrivate;

    }

    private static SecretKey generateSecretKey(int lenght) {


        SecretKey sKey = null;
        if ((lenght == 128) || (lenght == 192) || (lenght == 256)) {
            try {
                KeyGenerator kgen = KeyGenerator.getInstance("AES");
                kgen.init(lenght);
                sKey = kgen.generateKey();
            } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return sKey;

    }

    private static String encriptString(String stringtoencrypt) {

        byte[] stringtoencryptBytes = stringtoencrypt.getBytes();
        Cipher cipher = null;

        String stringEncrypted = null;
        try {
            cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
            IvParameterSpec iv = new IvParameterSpec(IV_PARAM);
            cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, secretKey, iv);

            // byte[] stringEncryptedBytes = cipher.doFinal(stringtoencryptBytes);
            ct = cipher.doFinal(stringtoencryptBytes);
            stringEncrypted = new String(cipher.doFinal(stringtoencryptBytes), "UTF-8");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


        return stringEncrypted;
    }


    private static String encriptKey(PublicKey aPublic) {
        String keyEncryptedString = null;
        try {
            Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA/ECB/PKCS1Padding");
            cipher.init(Cipher.WRAP_MODE, aPublic);
//            byte[] keyEncriptedBytes = cipher.wrap(secretKey);
//            keyEncryptedString = new String(keyEncriptedBytes, "UTF-8");
            wrapped = cipher.wrap(secretKey);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return keyEncryptedString;
    }

}
```

Note that both PKCS#1 padding (RSA encryption) nor CBC are susceptible to *padding oracle attacks*. You may want to use RSA/OAEP and GCM mode for AES.

Comment: Note that there are many other things wrong with the code. Exception handling is not OK (use `throw new RuntimeException(e)` if you don't know how to handle `e`). The checking of the AES key size is not fail fast; returning `null` is not a good idea. Never use `new String()` or `String#getBytes()` without specifying the character set (unless you need to use the default character set on your machine). Making everything `static` is certainly not OK; I hope that this is your "get it working" version :)